# setTimeout doesn't work when using Functional Inheritance

Tags: javascript, html, oop

after reading "JavaScript: The Good Parts" of Douglas Crockford, I tried to implement a timer like this. It has private variable (seconds, hours, minutes) and three public methods: start, stop and continue:

```
var timer = function() {
            var that = {};
            var seconds = 0;
            var hours = 0;
            var minutes = 0;
            var myTimer;

            that.getTime = function() {
                var time = hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds;
                return time;
            }
            that.start = function() {
                seconds += 1;           
                if(seconds >= 60) {
                    seconds -= 60;
                    minutes += 1;
                }
                if(minutes == 60)
                    hours += 1;
                document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
                document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
                document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds; 
                myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    start();
                }, 1000);
            };

            that.stop = function() {
                clearTimeout(myTimer);
            }
            that.reset = function() {
                seconds = 0;
                hours = 0;
                minutes = 0;
                clearTimeout(myTimer);
                document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;
                document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
                document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
            }
            return that;
        };
```

and then, I started it:

```
<body onload="var t = timer();t.start();">

    <h1>Digital Clock</h1>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li id="hours"></li>
                <li> : </li>
                <li id="minutes"></li>
                <li> : </li>
                <li id="seconds"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</body>
```

Can anyone tell me what errors did I make ?

**Update**: Finally, I found the problem.When you use a function from within another function (say, inner function), "this" is bound to **global**, not the outer function. Thus, in the statement start(), js will try to find a function in global object. Of course, there is no such function like this. Here, I found two solution:

1. use "that"

   myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                       that.start();
                   }, 1000);
2. Save the context:

   var timerInstance = this;

   myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                       timerInstance.start();
                   }, 1000);

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You should learn how to use the **console** to see what errors are being generated by your program. You can normally do this by pressing F12 within your browser (or Google). For *one* you should be using `this.start()` within your `start()` and `continue()` functions rather than *just* `start()`. You should also be assigning the result of `setTimeout()` to `myTimer` to enable your `stop()` function to work properly.

Comment: @Matt On this particular instance it's `that.start()`, not `this.start()`. This implementation of inheritence is absolutely unnecessary, I'm not sure, why they teach this.

Comment: @joncys: Indeed you're right. Well picked up ;) (although I can't correct my original comment as it's now outside the 5 minute window :))

Comment: Yes, I've implemented successfully the code without this template, I just want to learn how Functional Inheritance works, so I try to follow this template. But what is the exact problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle containing your modified code: http://jsfiddle.net/6YWLJ/

I've replaced "that" with "this" ("this" represents your timer) and instead of "var timer" i've used "window.timer"

Later edit: this is a version of corrected code, so it acts like a timer (you had some bugs in your code) http://jsfiddle.net/6YWLJ/2/

Comment: Thank you, But do you know why it didn't work with "that"? Perhaps the way I use this template looks stranger to you but as I'm reading that book, I just want to know as most as possible :)

Comment: I'm not sure. It might not be because of "that" but because of "var timer" instead of "window.timer". Here is the working jsFiddle updated with "that": http://jsfiddle.net/6YWLJ/5/

Comment: Thank you!! I found the error, here is what Crockford said in his book "When a function is invoked with this pattern (method invocation pattern), this is bound to the global object. This was a mistake in the design of the language. Had the language been designed correctly, when the inner function is invoked, this would still be bound to the this variable of the outer function. A consequence of this error is that a method cannot
employ an inner function to help it do its work because the inner function does not share the method’s access to the object as its this is bound to the wrong value..."